# How to write a unittest for POST function in Python (Trello)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, python-unittest, trello

I wanted to test a simple function like this, called 'posting.py':

```
import requests

def post():
        url = "https://api.trello.com/1/cards"
        params = {"key": "my_key",
                  "token": "my_token",
                  "name": "random_name",
                  "idList": "id"}
        response = requests.post(url=url, params=params)
        return response
post()
```

I created a file called 'posting_test.py', I know I have to import post.py, but after that I'm stuck. How can I test the response status code and assert that it's 200?

```
import unittest
from posting import post
```

Comment: There are many examples in the documentation of the unittest module, starting with a [basic example](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#basic-example). What is the exact issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very generally:

```
class Mytest(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_post(self):
        response = post()
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```